# OneSignal : how to customize action button for direct reply to notifications

Tags: cordova, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal with cordova SDK to push notifcations to users
and I must implement the feature that is direct reply as it is explained in [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#direct) for native application.

I've seen that it's possible to [customize action buttons](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/customize-action-buttons) and handle those events with [NotificationOpenedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-), but nothing like the direct reply action.

I'm at one point where I'm asking : how to customize action button for direct reply to notifications or **is it even possible to do so ?**

Thank you for your help,

Comment: If you mean a reply text field (like WhatsApp has), then I'm curious about this as well.

Comment: @GabrielLovetro Yes I was talking something like that and this is not possible according to sdk owners [https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/217](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/217)